# wxPython Background image on frame

Tags: python, graphics, bitmap, python-2.7, wxpython

MMGP Answerd but wont let me credit him right ;-)  So I will at least mention him here.
(And I did finally get to credit him...   8-)

[His linked discussion](http://wiki.wxpython.org/DoubleBufferedDrawing) on Double Buffering provided a base code that worked with the following modifications:

Insert this beginning at line 106 (overwritting existing code until you get to the last line shown here):

```
    # Here's the actual drawing code.
    cliWidth, cliHeight = self.GetClientSize()
    bmp=wx.Bitmap("Logo16x9.png")
    bmpWide = bmp.GetWidth()
    bmpHeight = bmp.GetHeight()
    img = bmp.ConvertToImage()
    scaleFactor = cliWidth/bmpWide
    bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(img.Scale(int(bmpWide * scaleFactor), int(bmpHeight * scaleFactor)))
    bmpWide = bmp.GetWidth()
    bmpHeight = bmp.GetHeight()
    xPos = (cliWidth - (bmpWide))/2
    yPos = (cliHeight - (bmpHeight))/2
    # altered by me
    dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, xPos, yPos)


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
```

I've been beating my head against this all day.

I'm new to drawing graphics with the wxPython modules, and when I needed to draw a background image on a frame I found [this code](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/) which works well if the image is the full size of the window.

However, I need to place a company logo as the background, and have it remain centered through resizes.  In it's current form the resize causes a graphic artifact the size of a small nation to appear on the screen with any resize event.

The logo image file (used on line 43 of the code) is a 400x300 (WxH) image.

I am looking for a way to either: resize my image on the fly to match wx.GetClientSize(),
or a way to avoid/remove the artifact.  Preferably without involving PIL or ImageMagick.  App has to function on a local level only, and be system agnostic (Win, Lin and Mac), none of this involves network activities or mapped drives.

Python 2.7 and wxPython 2.8

The code I am using (with my modification annotated) is as follows:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
        self.frame = parent

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        for num in range(4):
            label = "Button %s" % num
            btn = wx.Button(self, label=label)
            sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.TOP, 100)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 0, wx.ALL, 75)
        self.SetSizer(hSizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
        """
        Add a picture to the background
        """
        # yanked from ColourDB.py
        dc = evt.GetDC()
        # Added by me
        cliWidth, cliHeight = self.GetClientSize()

        if not dc:
            dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
            rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
            dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
        dc.Clear()
        # use a 400x300 image
        bmp = wx.Bitmap("Logo4x3.png")
        # added by me
        xPos = (cliWidth - 400)/2
        yPos = (cliHeight - 300)/2
        # altered by me
        dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, xPos, yPos)
        #dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)

########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(600,450))
        panel = MainPanel(self)        
        self.Center()

########################################################################
class Main(wx.App):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        dlg = MainFrame()
        dlg.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Update:  Latest Failure - Modified lines 37 to 52

```
if not dc:
    dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
    rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
    dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
dc.Clear()
# use a 400x300 image
bmp = wx.Bitmap("Logo4x3.png")
img = bmp.ConvertToImage()
scaleFactor = cliWidth/400
bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(img.Scale(int(400*scaleFactor),int(300*scaleFactor)))
# added by me
#xPos = (cliWidth - 400)/2
#yPos = (cliHeight - 300)/2
# altered by me
#dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, xPos, yPos)
dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)
```

Another attempt and another fail.  No difference in the output to screen.  Additionally, the referenced document on double buffering does not address this issue, but does suffer from the same result. This code modifies lines 36 through 57 of the original.

```
brsh = wx.Brush('#000000')


if not dc:
    dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
    rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
    dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
dc.SetBackground(brsh)
dc.SetDeviceOrigin(0,0)
dc.DestroyClippingRegion()
dc.Clear()
# use a 400x300 image
bmp = wx.Bitmap("Logo4x3.png")
img = bmp.ConvertToImage()
scaleFactor = cliWidth/400
bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(img.Scale(int(400*scaleFactor),int(300*scaleFactor)))
# added by me
#xPos = (cliWidth - 400)/2
#yPos = (cliHeight - 300)/2
# altered by me
#dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, xPos, yPos)
dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Is flicker the artifact you are referring to ? That is solved with double buffered drawing, specifically see http://wiki.wxpython.org/DoubleBufferedDrawing

Comment: no not a flicker.  A 75% copy of the original image remains after a redraw.  Result looks like the two squares (coloredf) overlapping by 25%.  (generalization, the logo is square)

Comment: better explanation.  Original image never erases.  New image (after resize) is drawn in correctly, but now both images are on the surface.  Oddly enough, the new image draws below (lower z-index) the old image.

Comment: To me it seems the previous link still applies. Did you check it ?

Comment: @mmgp  Was just posting about that...the link on double buffering crosses the same field, but does not address the failed erase step.  ALso (failed to note this above) have tried to bind this to EXT_SIZE and EVT_PAINT with no difference in results.

Comment: @mmgp  OK with A LOT of fiddling I've gotten the Double Buffering code to correct part of the problem (the artifact is gone) but now the rest of the window is "off", but that can be fixed.  If you would be so kind as to post your suggestion as an answer, I will credit you.  Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: On OSX the first code you posted almost works. I had to remove `self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)` because it was causing the repainting to fail in all possible ways (buttons weren't not redraw properly, background image never shown).

Comment: I still have two problems with the new code (based on your suggest), it wont draw the image at all if the window isnt at least bmp.GetSize()+1, and second problem is.....I CANT GIVE YOU CREDIT FOR ANSWER!!  hint..hint..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments I suggested using double buffered drawing, but I didn't see that in the edited post. Also, I had several drawing issues when `self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)` was used. But this line might be helpful in other systems beyond mine, so I wanted to keep it. So, in order to handle the situation, here is a updated code that uses double buffered drawing and works fine here:

```
import wx

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, bg_img='Logo4x3.png'):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
        self.bg = wx.Bitmap(bg_img)
        self._width, self._height = self.bg.GetSize()

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        for num in range(4):
            btn = wx.Button(self, label="Button %s" % num)
            sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.TOP, 100)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 0, wx.ALL, 75)
        self.SetSizer(hSizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)

    def OnSize(self, size):
        self.Layout()
        self.Refresh()

    def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
        pass

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
        self.Draw(dc)

    def Draw(self, dc):
        cliWidth, cliHeight = self.GetClientSize()
        if not cliWidth or not cliHeight:
            return
        dc.Clear()
        xPos = (cliWidth - self._width)/2
        yPos = (cliHeight - self._height)/2
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bg, xPos, yPos)

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, size=(400,300))
panel = MainPanel(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

The method `OnEraseBackground` is intentionally empty.

Comment: Thanks for the extra code...I was just about to try to strip all the nonsense out of the original example you linked.  This will make life much easier.  Now to start rebuilding my idea based on this....

Comment: Does this work on Linux too ? I can't test it there right now.

Comment: Failed horribly in some WM I tried over there, will get back to this.

Comment: See the updated code in case the earlier one failed for you somewhere.