# Scaling background image with frame size using wx python

Tags: python, background, panel, wxwidgets, frame

I've been experimenting with eventually having an application that uses a simple vector image as a background, so the screen can be scaled and resized as needed. I've been testing this with a raster photograph for the time being and trying to cobble something together with the following links:

https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/
[How to resize and draw an image using wxpython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504143/how-to-resize-and-draw-an-image-using-wxpython)
[wxPython Background image on frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789636/wxpython-background-image-on-frame)

Unfortunately I'm noobish, and while I get the gist of what's going on I don't have enough experience to modify it for my own purposes. That being said, how do I keep a background image on a panel and scale the image with the panel size in real-time using wxpython?

I have some cobbled code right now:

```
import pathlib
import wx

class MainApp(wx.App):

    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):

        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        dlg = MainFrame(parent=None,title="IvyVine")
        dlg.Show()

####################################

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="IvyVine",size=(1000,500))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Center()

        self.Show(True)

    def OnExit(self,e):
        self.Close(True) #Closes the frame

####################################

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        bg_img = 'window.JPG'

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_ERASE)
        self.frame = parent
        self.bg = wx.Bitmap(bg_img)
        self._width, self._height = self.bg.GetSize()

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        for num in range(3):
            label = "Button %s" % num
            btn = wx.Button(self,label=label)
            sizer.Add(btn,0,wx.ALL,5)

        hSizer.Add((1,1), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.TOP, 100)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 0, wx.ALL, 75)
        self.SetSizer(hSizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    #---------------------------

    def scale_bg(self, bitmap, width, height):

        pass

    #---------------------------

    def OnSize(self, size):

        self.Layout()
        self.Refresh()

    #---------------------------

    def OnPaint(self, evt):

        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
        self.Draw(dc)

    #---------------------------

    def Draw(self, dc):

        cliWidth, cliHeight = self.GetClientSize()
        if not cliWidth or not cliHeight:
            return
        dc.Clear()

        # The image I'm using is very large, and this math only captures a part of it for some reason.
        xPos = (cliWidth - self._width)/2
        yPos = (cliHeight - self._height)/2
        #img = self.scale_bg(self.bg)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bg, xPos, yPos)

#################################

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = MainApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

****EDITED CODE****

```
####################################
```

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

```
def __init__(self, parent):

    bg_img = 'window.JPG'

    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
    self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_ERASE)
    self.frame = parent
    self.bg = wx.Image(bg_img, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
    #store sizes
    self.bgh = self.bg.GetHeight()
    self.bgw = self.bg.GetWidth()

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    for num in range(3):
        label = "Button %s" % num
        btn = wx.Button(self,label=label)
        sizer.Add(btn,0,wx.ALL,5)

    hSizer.Add((1,1), 1, wx.EXPAND)
    hSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.TOP, 100)
    hSizer.Add((1,1), 0, wx.ALL, 75)
    self.SetSizer(hSizer)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

#---------------------------

def OnSize(self, size):

    self.Layout()
    self.Refresh()

#---------------------------

def OnPaint(self, evt):

    dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
    self.Draw(dc)

#---------------------------

def Draw(self, dc):

    cliWidth, cliHeight = self.GetClientSize()
    if not cliWidth or not cliHeight:
        return
    dc.Clear()

    #calculate scale factors
    fw = cliWidth / float(self.bgw)
    fh = cliHeight / float(self.bgh)
    scaledimage = self.bg_img.Scale(fw, fh)

    dc.DrawBitmap(wx.Bitmap(scaledimage))
```

#

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `wx.Image`, it can't be scaled. Use [wx.Image](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Image.html#wx-image).

```
def __init__(self, parent):

    bg_img = 'window.JPG'

    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
    self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_ERASE)
    self.frame = parent
    self.bg = wx.Image(bg_img, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
    #---store sizes---
    self.bgh = bg.GetHeight()
    self.bgw = bg.GetWidth()
```

Next, in your Draw function, scale the image and draw it

```
def Draw(self, dc):

    cliWidth, cliHeight = self.GetClientSize()
    if not cliWidth or not cliHeight:
        return
    dc.Clear()

    # Calculate scale factors
    # The final image will be distorted. Change this maths for "fit in window", but leaving margins
    fw = cliWidth / float(self.bgw)
    fh = cliHeight / float(self.bgh)
    scaledimage = self.bg.Scale(fw, fh)

    #dc wants a Bitmap
    dc.DrawBitmap(wx.Bitmap(scaledimage))
```

Comment: Thank you! Only one issue; how do I initiate the draw method? Right now the program background remains blank

Comment: @WatcherMagic. Weird. Your `Draw` is called from `OnPaint`, which should happen automatically from `MainFrame.Show`. Use a debugger to get sure it's called. Aside note: I've edited my answer since `fh,fw` were misscalculated, but it has nothing to do with not seeing the image.

Comment: I have an error that says 'MainPanel object as no attribute bg_img', I've edited my post to have the current code. (Thanks for the corrections!)

Comment: @WatcherMagic Oh, sorry, my fault. It has to be `bg` (a wx.Image) instead of `bg_img` ( a text). I've edited my answer.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! Thank you! There's not much change, something about "C++ assertion "(width > 0) && (height > 0)" failed at ..\..\src\common\image.cpp(433) in wxImage::Scale(): invalid new image size". I'm going to experiment with the mathematics, I'll post if something works.

Comment: @WatcherMagic That assertion may be due to initially (before first shown, some wx innards) size of the window is [-1,-1]. Just handle this case (i.e. 'return') right after `self.GetClientSize()`

Comment: alright, if I put just 'return' afterward the program loads with the background black. I think this is a far as I'm going to look into the issue though, I'm new to python and want to explore some other libraries before trying to dive too deep into a single issue. Thank you so much for your help though! It's been a pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

The [Image.Scale](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Image.html#wx.Image.Scale) method waits for integers. The new size of the image should be given instead of the ratio.

Also, the [DC.DrawBitmap](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.DC.html?highlight=drawbitmap#wx.DC.DrawBitmap) method is missing the position of the image in the panel as input parameters (x=0, y=0).

With these fixes, the Draw method becomes:

```py
     def Draw(self, dc):
    
        cliWidth, cliHeight = self.GetClientSize()
        if not cliWidth or not cliHeight:
            return
        dc.Clear()
    
        #Scale to client size
        scaledimage = self.bg_img.Scale(cliWidth, cliHeight)
        dc.DrawBitmap(wx.Bitmap(scaledimage), 0, 0)
```